# How to find the number of Markers in a Marker Array?

Tags: pcl, markerarray, message, msg, marker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

I'm trying to write a simple program that extracts the heights from all the markers in a MarkerArray message. However, I am having a lot of trouble doing this.

This is how I get the cartesian information:
msg->markers[i].pose.position.z

I read somewhere that this might work, but so far no luck:
msg->markers.size()

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68362/how-to-find-the-number-of-markers-in-a-marker-array?/) by [AG1617](https://answers.ros.org/users/4890/ag1617/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*msg->markers.size()* gives you the number of markers contained in the message.

To find or set the height, have a look at the *scale* fields of the marker message (see also http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Message_Parameters).

---

Originally posted by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) with karma: 529 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1